# How do i fix my attach button ot run button in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

It just says attach but I don't know how to run instead of attach

Comment: Did you start by creating a Project or a File? You need to create a Project in order to run. When you open a project, the button will change to "Start".

Comment: what type of project????

Comment: it still wont work it just says attach

Comment: Where does it say that?